# immutable value with mutable input reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, material-ui

I have the values of `yearOfEnforcementProceesdings + cityOfEnforcementProceedings` which are defined in advance, and there is a `serialNumber` that needs to be entered, and so that when changing the serialNumber field, 2 more unchanged values would be displayed

```
state = {
  serialumber: 1,
  yearOfEnforcementProceesdings: 2019, 
  cityOfEnforcementProceedings: 75
}    
onChangeSerial = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({
      serialNumber:
       value +
        this.state.yearOfEnforcementProceesdings +
        this.state.cityOfEnforcementProceedings
    });
};

  <TextField        
      onChange={this. onChangeSerial}
      value={serialNumber}
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
    />
```

expectation: `serialNumber + 2019 + 75`

reality: `serialNumber +  2019 + 75 serialNumber  2019 + 75 serialNumber  2019 + 75 and so on`

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-custom-textfield-composition-whor8

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact you are providing this compound value to the textfield, then you sum actualCompoundValue + newCompoundValue every time you to `setState()`

Try the following:

```
 onChangeSerial = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({
      serialNumber: `serialNumber ${this.state.yearOfEnforcementProceesdings} ${this.state.cityOfEnforcementProceedings}`,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is displaying the result in the input itself. Consider if a user changes the value or continues typing, your idea would keep repeating the suffix over and over.

The solution is to separate the input from the result display:

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-custom-textfield-composition-c82se)

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    serialNumber: "",
    serialNumberFull: "",
    yearOfEnforcementProceedings: "2019",
    cityOfEnforcementProceedings: "75"
  };

  onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({
      serialNumber : value,
      serialNumberFull: `${value}${this.state.yearOfEnforcementProceedings}${this.state.cityOfEnforcementProceedings}`,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { serialNumber, serialNumberFull } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
       <TextField value={serialNumber} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <label>{serialNumberFull}</label>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```